# What collation can be used in MySQL 5.5 for sorting Japanese characters?

Tags: mysql, collation, utf8mb4

I have a database with utf8mb4 character set and Ive been trying to select records where data are in Japanese characters but the utf8mb4_general_ci collation can't seem to order the result correctly. for example , the below characters are showing in desc order:

> 小松

> 児玉

when it should be:

> 児玉

> 小松

Comment: MySQL 5.5 is pretty old. All kinds of support have ended nearly three years ago. Have you checked whether updating to a supported version of MySQL resolves the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's our restriction , we are not allowed to upgrade it.

Comment: Do you know what is with utf8mb4_general_ci that makes it unable to sort Japanese characters? or any articles which talks about this?

Comment: @Fancy did you check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-cjk.html ?

Comment: Thanks @ErgestBasha yes i found the same FAQs for 5.5 version, very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Okay , For others who might stamble upon this same situation .
Here is the solution i found. So , i read this article

[MySQL 5.5 FAQ: MySQL Chinese, Japanese, and Korean Character Sets](http://doc.docs.sk/mysql-refman-5.5/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-B-11-1-14)

I'll post here snippet of what it says:

```
    mysql> SELECT * FROM tj WHERE s1 = 'か';
    +------+
    | s1   |
    +------+
    | が  |
    | か  |
    +------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> The character in the first result row is not the one that we searched
> for. Why did MySQL retrieve it? First we look for the Unicode code
> point value, which is possible by reading the hexadecimal number for
> the ucs2 version of the characters:

```
mysql> SELECT s1, HEX(CONVERT(s1 USING ucs2)) FROM tj;
+------+-----------------------------+
| s1   | HEX(CONVERT(s1 USING ucs2)) |
+------+-----------------------------+
| が  | 304C                        |
| か  | 304B                        |
+------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

> Now we search for 304B and 304C in the 4.0.0 allkeys table, and find
> these lines:
>
> 304B  ; [.1E57.0020.000E.304B] # HIRAGANA LETTER KA

> 304C  ; [.1E57.0020.000E.304B][.0000.0140.0002.3099] # HIRAGANA LETTER GA;

> QQCM The official Unicode names (following the “#” mark) tell us the
> Japanese syllabary (Hiragana), the informal classification (letter,
> digit, or punctuation mark), and the Western identifier (KA or GA,
> which happen to be voiced and unvoiced components of the same letter
> pair). More importantly, the primary weight (the first hexadecimal
> number inside the square brackets) is 1E57 on both lines. For
> comparisons in both searching and sorting, MySQL pays attention to the
> primary weight only, ignoring all the other numbers. This means that
> we are sorting が and か correctly according to the Unicode
> specification. If we wanted to distinguish them, we'd have to use a
> non-UCA (Unicode Collation Algorithm) collation (utf8_bin or
> utf8_general_ci), or to compare the HEX() values, or use ORDER BY
> CONVERT(s1 USING sjis). Being correct “according to Unicode” isn't
> enough, of course: the person who submitted the bug was equally
> correct. We plan to add another collation for Japanese according to
> the JIS X 4061 standard, in which voiced/unvoiced letter pairs like
> KA/GA are distinguishable for ordering purposes.

As what the article suggested, I used " ORDER BY CONVERT(s1 USING sjis)" as a workaround to resolve my problem.

Comment: unfortunately this workaround is still not accurately sorting the Japanese characters.

Comment: Would 5.2.0 or 9.0.0 do better?  They are available in later versions of MySQL.